# How can I tell PEX from polybutylene pipe?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, pex

There's a blue pipe (1" diameter) extending ~3 feet from the city water meter before transitioning to 1" copper, then the copper connects 2 feet later to my rusted galvanized. I've run new pex-a pipe throughout the house, copper for above-ground section (e.g. hose bibs, shut-off valve), and planned to run pvc schedule 80 to the service line. Thought the service line was copper but turns out it's a blue pipe.

How do I know if this is pex pipe or polybutylene? I don't see any markings. Appears to be connected to the copper pipe with a compression union. I don't know when it was installed. [image: blue pipe]

Comment: Have you asked your water utility? They may have a standard for connecting to their meters and may require you to stop your run at this rather muddy union.

Comment: was hesitant to raise a flag -- I am repiping and doing other work without permits. I'll call them anyway since I know that's the most accurate way to get an answer. My plan was to remove this union and tap into the blue pipe, though I don't know why there's a 2' segment of copper between the blue and galvanized (presumably installed by the city too...)

Comment: How do you turn the supply off?

Comment: there's a shut-off valve at the water meter. Talked with the city today, couldn't get a straight answer as to whether it is polybutylene or pex, but was told I should be able to tap into this coupler with pvc 40/80 no problem.

Comment: Probably PEX. It's not gray, which most or all PB is. If you excavate and clean about 3 feet you can likely read the printing on it. On the third hand, you don't need to know, it's got a perfectly good fitting on it already.

Comment: thanks! I read that PB sometimes came in blue but generally was gray. Google-diving says my City recently (2017-2021) updated water meters which also points towards PEX. An hour ago the City water guy conveniently showed up and said I should be able to tap into the existing fitting with PVC, and gave me an "insert stiffener" which may come in handy for this

Comment: PEX and PB are not your only options. it could also be MDPE

Answer (score 4):

Every picture I've seen of polybutylene [shows it as pale blue](https://www.nachi.org/pb.htm)

[image: polybutylene pipe]

PEX is almost always bright blue (when it is blue). In addition, polybutylene breaks down over time. The chances it's survived in a water main this long is low.

Comment: looks correct to me. The consensus is PEX. Thanks all!

Comment: It could be a waterworks/utility grade PE pipe for that matter

Answer (score 2):

The copper side of the joiner will have a standard thread, connect there. leave the mystery blue plastic side undisturbed.

Dig under the join so you can recconect it without grit getting into the threads.

Comment: I thought maybe it was a compression coupling, but are you saying it's probably a standard female thread? If so I can connect with a male PVC fitting

Comment: it looks like brass, and if it it is it's a standard pipe nipple. so yeah a it should thread into other pipe fittings.  for copper pipe compression fittings are just compression nuts and ferrules on a pipe nipple.