# replacing service line, connecting to blue pipe?

Tags: plumbing, water

My city water service line is this blue pipe (I have another question about this [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/238550/polybutylene-or-pex)).

Currently the blue pipe is connected to  a short 2' section of copper with what looks like a compression union, and 2' further down the copper is connected to ~25' of galvanized pipe before reaching my house.

I have run 3/4" and 1/2" PEX-A throughout the house in the crawlspace and will use copper for daylighted sections (i.e. hose bib, shut-off valve), and am determining what material to use for the 1" service line.

I was planning to cut out the copper and galvanized pipe, and connect PVC Schedule 80 to the blue pipe. I chose PVC Sch 80 because it is tougher than PVC Sch 40, cheaper than copper and easier to get than copper or PEX-A right now, though I'm not set on this.

What would be the appropriate way to connect PVC schedule 80 to this blue pipe?

I am also open to suggestions for alternatives to PVC schedule 80.

[image: hole in the ground with copper pipe, a union and some sort of blue plastic pipe]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What kind of pipe is this?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/238550/what-kind-of-pipe-is-this)

Comment: The other question asks about what kind of pipe it is (and doesn't have an answer, though the answer is in the comments). This one asks about how to connect to it.

Comment: that other question was mine. I know stackexchange requires questions to be separated as a Q&A rather than forum format. FreeMan is right about the other question being answered. I should be able to connect to the existing fitting with PVC, as I mentioned in my response to Ecnerwal's answer. Just waiting on confirmation :)

Answer (score 2):

There does not appear to be a particuarly good reason to remove the 2 feet of copper, which:

- Connects to the blue pipe
- Presumably has a standard pipe thread connection to the "rusty galvanized" pipe, since that's how things usually connect to galvanized pipe.
- Is therefore easy to connect PVC (or whatever) to.

Otherwise you're going on a snipe hunt for a PVC (or whatever) to (what looks to be) compression fitting adapter to work with the fittings you have shown on the copper and blue plastic - but you already have a 2 foot long copper (thus not rusty) adapter which terminates in bog standard easy to find pipe threads.

Comment: The copper line isn't in great shape -- strange curve in it, a few minor dents, and the sweat fitting on it is leaking (albiet very minor). I could cut the end, clean the pipe of debris and attach a new sweat-to-female-thread fitting, though that sounded more time consuming than tapping into the existing compression fitting. The City water guy said I should be able to attach PVC straight into the existing coupling, assuming the coupling is still in good shape. Does that sound right?